# Плагин Bookradar для Calibre

Tags: python, плагин

Имеется плагин для каталогизатора книг Calibre. в винде не ставится из-за requests и bs4. Прошу помочь переписать без них. плагин представляет собой скрипт питона

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (unicode_literals, division, absolute_import, print_function)

import re
from Queue import Queue, Empty
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from calibre import as_unicode
from calibre.utils.date import parse_only_date
from calibre.ebooks.metadata import check_isbn
from calibre.ebooks.metadata.book.base import Metadata
from calibre.ebooks.metadata.sources.base import Source, Option


class BookradarMetadataSourcePlugin(Source):

name = 'Bookradar'

capabilities = frozenset(['identify', 'cover'])
touched_fields = frozenset(('title', 'authors', 'identifier:isbn', 'publisher', 'pubdate'))


url_pattern = 'http://bookradar.org/search/?q=%s&type=all'

@classmethod
def find(cls, base_element, class_name, single=False):
    found = base_element.find_all('div', class_=class_name)
    if single:
        if not found:
            return ''
        return found[0].text.strip()
    return found

@classmethod
def parse_response(cls, response, title_initial, author_initial, isbn_initial, log):
    global page_soup
    metadata_items = []

    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

    for idx, candidate in enumerate(cls.find(page_soup, 'b-result'), 1):

        title = cls.find(candidate, 'b-result__name-wrap', True)
        author = map(unicode.strip, cls.find(candidate, 'b-result__author', True).split(','))
        comments = cls.find(candidate, 'b-result__desc__full', True).replace(u'Скрыть', '').strip()
        isbn = cls.find(candidate, 'b-result__isbn', True).split(':')[-1].split(',')[0].strip()

        log.info(u'Found candidate %s: %s' % (idx, title))

        publisher = None
        pubdate = None
        other_info = cls.find(candidate, 'b-result__years', True).strip()
        if other_info:
            for entry in other_info.split(';'):
                k, v = entry.split(':', 1)
                k = k.strip()
                if k == u'Год':
                    pubdate = parse_only_date('1.1.%s' % v.split(',')[0].strip())
                elif k == u'Издательство':
                    publisher = v.strip()

        metadata_item = Metadata(title, author)
        metadata_item.isbn = isbn or isbn_initial
        if comments:
            metadata_item.comments = comments

        if publisher is not None:
            metadata_item.publisher = publisher

        if pubdate is not None:
            metadata_item.pubdate = pubdate

        metadata_items.append(metadata_item)

    return metadata_items

def is_customizable(self):
    return False

def identify(self, log, result_queue, abort, title=None, authors=None, identifiers=None, timeout=30):
    log.info(u'Bookradar identification started ...')

    identifiers = identifiers or {}
    search_tokens = []

    if title:
        search_tokens += list(self.get_title_tokens(title))

    if authors:
        search_tokens += list(self.get_author_tokens(authors, only_first_author=True))

    isbn = check_isbn(identifiers.get('isbn', None))
    if isbn:
        search_tokens += (isbn,)

    search_str = ' '.join(search_tokens)
    url = self.url_pattern % search_str

    log.info(u'Searching for: %s' % search_str)

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        log.exception('Failed to get data from `%s`: %s' % (url, e.message))
        return as_unicode(e)

    metadata = self.parse_response(response, title, authors, isbn, log=log)

    for result in metadata:
        self.clean_downloaded_metadata(result)
        result_queue.put(result)

def download_cover(self, log, result_queue, abort, title=None, authors=None, identifiers={}, timeout=30, get_best_cover=False):  # {{{
    log.info(u'Bookradar identification started ...')

    identifiers = identifiers or {}
    search_tokens = []
    cached_url = None
    if title:
        search_tokens += list(self.get_title_tokens(title))

    isbn = check_isbn(identifiers.get('isbn', None))
    if isbn:
        search_tokens += (isbn,)

    search_str = ' '.join(search_tokens)
    url = self.url_pattern % search_str

    log.info(u'Searching for: %s' % search_str)

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        log.exception('Failed to get data from `%s`: %s' % (url, e.message))
        return as_unicode(e)

    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
emb = None
    for img in page_soup.findAll('img', src=True):
    emb = img['src'].strip()
    if emb.lower().endswith('.jpg') or emb.lower().endswith('.jpeg'):

    break
if emb is None: 
    log.info('No cover found')
else:
    cached_url=emb
log.info('Downloading cover from:', cached_url)
    try:
        cdata = self.browser.open_novisit(cached_url, timeout=timeout).read()
        if cdata:
            result_queue.put((self, cdata))
    except Exception as e:
        log.exception(u'Failed to download cover from: %s'%cached_url)
        return as_unicode(e)
if __name__ == '__main__':
# Tests
# calibre-customize -b . && calibre-debug -e __init__.py

from calibre.ebooks.metadata.sources.test import (test_identify_plugin, title_test, authors_test, isbn_test)

test_identify_plugin(BookradarMetadataSourcePlugin.name, [
    (
        {'identifiers': {'isbn': '9785932861578'}},
        [
            title_test(u'Python. Подробный справочник', exact=True),
            authors_test([u'Дэвид Бизли'])
        ]
    ),
    (
        {
            'title': u'справочник',
            'identifiers': {'isbn': '9785932861578'}
        },
        [
            title_test(u'Python. Подробный справочник', exact=True),
            authors_test([u'Дэвид Бизли'])
        ]
    ),
    (
        {
            'title': u'Opencv Computer Vision',
            'authors': u'Howse'
        },
        [
            title_test(u'Opencv Computer Vision with Python', exact=True),
            authors_test([u'Joseph Howse'])
        ]
    ),
])
```

Comment: как requests так и beautifulsoup4 являются библиотеками, написанными на чистом Питоне (не должно быть никаких сложностей использовать их на любой системе, где python вообще работает). Я не знаком как calibre на Windows ставится, попробуйте: `calibre-debug -c 'import pip, sys; sys.exit(pip.main())' install requests beautifulsoup4` выполнить.

Answer (score 2):

Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. Установите требуемые библиотеки requests и bs4. Затем найдите их папки, requests и bs4 соотвественно и добавьте их в архив pylib.zip, который лежит в корне Calibre.